# Send an email from shell script which has clickable link in it

Tags: shell, unix, ksh, informatica, informatica-powercenter

I want to send an email from `informatica` post session command such that the email has clickable link in it..

Following is my code:

```
#Name: rse_outbound_feeds_email_Invoice_link_mail                         #
#Author: Blossom Correia                                  # 
#Date created (mm/dd/yyyy): 04/26/2016                                    #
#Purpose: This script will send an email with the link to the user for Email invoiced report      #
###################################################################################################


Target_dir=/data/rse_outbound_feeds/tgtfiles
File_name=Emailed_invoice_`date '+%Y%m%d'`.csv
Mail_to_recipients=correia.blossom@rexelholdingsusa.com

 #checking size of the Target file
 if [ -s $Target_dir/$File_name ]
 then
    echo "Hi," > invoice_mail.html
    echo "            " >> invoice_mail.html
    echo "Please click on the link below for the email events latest Email_Invoice file" >>invoice_mail.html
    echo "<html><body><a href="\\corp-serv3.rexelusa.com\Dev\Business Intelligence\Reports\Emailed_Invoices\">Link text</a></body></html>">>invoice_mail.html
    echo "\\corp-serv3.rexelusa.com\Dev\Business Intelligence\Reports\Emailed_Invoices\ " >> invoice_mail.html
    echo "            " >> invoice_mail.html
    echo "NOTE: This is auto generated email with an unmonitored mailbox. Please do not reply to this email." >> invoice_mail.html
    echo "            " >> invoice_mail.html
    echo "Thanks," >> invoice_mail.html
    echo "RHUSA Business Intelligence Support Team." >> invoice_mail.html
        mutt -s "eServ Rexel- Emailed Invoice Report" ${Mail_to_recipients} -y< invoice_mail.html


    else
    exit 0
fi
                rm -f /data/rse_outbound_feeds/scripts/invoice_mail.html
     #           mv $Target_dir/$File_name   /ff1_arc/rse_outbound_feeds/inbfiles/
#end of the script
```

but i am getting an error while executing the script:

> line 11: syntax error at line 20: `<' unexpected

If I try it without html then I get plain text in the mail without the link.
Note that the location is the file location and not a web link.

It is possible to send it as a link either in `Informatica` post session command or email task?

Answer (score 0):

To fix this you could have used this [great site](http://www.shellcheck.net/) I discovered here, and paste your code in it for error checking.

### Your main quoted string with the `href` is not correct + you must escape the `\` char with `\`

Try this:

```
#Name: rse_outbound_feeds_email_Invoice_link_mail                         #
#Author: Blossom Correia                                  # 
#Date created (mm/dd/yyyy): 04/26/2016                                    #
#Purpose: This script will send an email with the link to the user for Email invoiced report      #
###################################################################################################


Target_dir=/data/rse_outbound_feeds/tgtfiles
File_name=Emailed_invoice_`date '+%Y%m%d'`.csv
Mail_to_recipients=correia.blossom@rexelholdingsusa.com

 #checking size of the Target file
 if [ -s $Target_dir/$File_name ]
 then
    echo "<html><body>Hi," > invoice_mail.html
    echo "<br>            " >> invoice_mail.html
    echo "Please click on the link below for the email events latest Email_Invoice file" >>invoice_mail.html
    echo "<a href=\"\\\\\\\\corp-serv3.rexelusa.com\\Dev\\Business Intelligence\\Reports\\Emailed_Invoices\">Link text</a>" >>invoice_mail.html
    echo "<br>            " >> invoice_mail.html
    echo "NOTE: This is auto generated email with an unmonitored mailbox. Please do not reply to this email." >> invoice_mail.html
    echo "<br>            " >> invoice_mail.html
    echo "Thanks," >> invoice_mail.html
    echo "<br>            " >> invoice_mail.html
    echo "RHUSA Business Intelligence Support Team.</body></html>" >> invoice_mail.html
        mutt -s "eServ Rexel- Emailed Invoice Report" ${Mail_to_recipients} -y< invoice_mail.html    

    else
    exit 0
fi
rm -f /data/rse_outbound_feeds/scripts/invoice_mail.html
```

### Or for your new requirement:

```
mutt -s "eServ Rexel- Emailed Invoice Report" ${Mail_to_recipients} -y< EmailInvoice.html
```

alone should work...

Comment: is there any other way if not using href i found it while surfing through some codes

Comment: Probably... but I was answering your question. You must split big problems into smaller ones if you want to move forward the easy way.

Comment: initially i had created a text file with plain text and sent it as mail and it was successful so later i tried making the changes to send it as html

Comment: did you try my answer? I modified your code, it should work now.

Comment: in my email i am getting as follows: " Hi,
            
Please click on the link below for the email events latest Email_Invoice file <html><body><a href="\corp-serv3.rexelusa.com\Dev\Business Intelligence\Reports\Emailed_Invoices">Link text</a></body></html> \corp-serv3.rexelusa.com\Dev\Business Intelligence\Reports\Emailed_Invoices\ 
            
NOTE: This is auto generated email with an unmonitored mailbox. Please do not reply to this email.
            
Thanks,
RHUSA Business Intelligence Support Team.
"

Comment: I still don't understand what is it you want. It doesn't look like correct `html` generated though... I updated the answer to make it better html.

Comment: no no it is still displaying entire html hash tags.. i created a separate html file with my mail content with name 'EmailInvoice.html'... Can you please tell if i can just add it in mail body section by some way.. this file name i have assigned to a variable contents with its full path and file name

Comment: First, why do we have backslashes in the link? Shouldn't it work with forward slashes too? We don't have to worry about escaping then. Second, shouldn't a link to a local file start with `file:`?